# Need help with terminology so that I can source a din rail version of this part

Tags: power-supply, batteries, ups, backup

Im looking for a 12 VDC power supply that has the ability to switch to a battery when ac power is lost in addition to having some type of AC status function such as an open collector. This part does everything I need but I would prefer one that can mount on a DIN rail. Can anyone suggest one or help me with some better search keywords.

[image]
https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=PSC-60&mws=E8F3D2F026E800B6

Similar to https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/ac-dc-industrial-din-rail-power-supply-output-dr--ups40 but they only make this model in 24v
[image]

The only things im finding that are close with "DIN rail UPS", and "DIN rail power supply with battery backup" are devices meant for industrial automation that typically cost ALOT more.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Add enough photos and text that we can understand what you're asking without following links.

Comment: I just added some images, thanks

Answer (score 1):

DIN is commonly used in industrial applications and, in Europe, in domestic fuseboards. Your DIN PSU will most likely be for industrial applications and will be priced accordingly.

I would be inclined to use the PSU that does the job at the price you want and modify it to mount on the DIN rail.

[image]

*Figure 1. A quick search for "DIN rail clip" throws up plenty of options.*